# SSRS FetchXML Report works in Visual Studi - empty in Dynamics 365

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, ssrs-tablix, dynamics-365, fetchxml

I at my whits end.

I have spent the last couple of days building a very in depth and mildly interactive report in Visual Studio 2015 (yes, I know but SMT wont let me upgrade to later version).

The report work fine in VS2015 but when uploaded to Dynamics 365, it is empty. The very odd thing though - the 'blank' report has the right number (3) pages however they are empty other than the header and footer.

I have a few Parameters that the user can choose from and it is the first time using these (just to set viability for a few tablix).

I don't even know where to start with searching this - all the results I am getting relate to reports having extra blank pages at the end but nothing about just coming up empty but still having the right number of pages.

I'm sorry that this seem (is) a bit of a wishy washy question. I just dont even know where to start asking for help...

EDIT: The problem appears to be with `EnablePreFiltering="True"` If I disable this, the report will run and return many many many pages and they are all formatted correctly. I have built my report so that everything is inside a single `List` which I apply the current users record to. Again - the problem is here somewhere.

Edit: (Wine has just been opened and the laptop charger is out - going to be a long night)

Comment: When you disabled prefiltering, you see report for all the users? what you want is to see report for particular user? question, when EnablePreFiltering="True" and the record you are running your report on, does it have data to show report?
Next question: `<entity name="account" enableprefiltering="1" prefilterparametername="CRM_FilteredAccount">` when you enable prefilter you do have prefilterparameter?

Comment: Yes: When I disable prefiltering, I see the report (correctly) for all users - takes ages, produces something around 2800 pages in D365's native report viewer. With `EnablePreFiltering="True"` I get no data from D365. What I do not have is the `prefilterparametername="CRM_FilteredAccount"` - I'm going to go and give that a shot now.

Comment: Update - Absolutely no idea... I made the change you stated above, got an error in D365 stating an error with the RDL file and it can't upload. Reverted to the previous version and it now works 100%. Exactly as intended. There is something to do with our instance of D365 that does not allow me to use `EnablePreFiltering="1"` - I have to use `="true"` - that is where the error was coming from.

Comment: Does that mean your issue is resolved?

Comment: Does that mean your issue is resolved? crm_filteredaccoount was just an example stating that when you do prefiltering it does on hidden parameter created by report in dynamics crm.

Comment: Appears not - the problem has come back. I just tried to run the report again and it is blank again...

Comment: can I suggest a parallel way, First create a Report in CRM directly using [report wizard](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/sandeepmishracrmblog/posts/create-reports-in-dynamics-crm) once the report is created, download it and use Visual studio to customize/change it. Why from CRM because you will get enable prefiltering and other parameters out of box from crm and I believe in your case it has to do with parameters which are not correctly configured.

Comment: Did this ever get resolved?  We are running into the exact same issue?